# html5 onkeydown, check if a form element is selected

Tags: html, html5-canvas, onkeydown

I'm working on an html5 canvas game and am using document.onkeydown to test input.  However, I  want to add a check in the onkeydown to make sure no form elements are selected, particularly the chat box.  How do I check for that?

Here's my code for onkeydown

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
                var keyCode;

                if(event == null)
                {
                    keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
                }
                else
                {
                    keyCode = event.keyCode;
                }
                var message = {
                    'msgId': 4
                };

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    // left
                    case 65:
                        message['move'] = 0;
                        connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                        break;

                    // up
                    case 87:
                        message['move'] = 1;
                        connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                        break;

                    // right
                    case 68:
                        message['move'] = 2;
                        connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                        break;

                    // down
                    case 83:
                        message['move'] = 3;
                        connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                        break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can u show some code ?

Comment: I've added what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an html Canvas does not receive it's own keyboard events.

But if you give a canvas a tabindex, it then *does receive its own keyboard events.*

```
    // set canvas to be a tab stop (necessary to get keydown events)

    myCanvas.setAttribute('tabindex','0');
```

Then you can listen for key events specifically on your canvas rather than the window.

```
    // have handleKeydown handle keydown events on the canvas

    myCanvas.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeydown,false);
```

As with all text input elements, the use must click on the canvas to give it focus.

But, you can force the canvas to have focus

```
    // set focus to the canvas so keystrokes are immediately handled

    canvas.focus();
```

**[ Addition -- determining if the key event was raised in an input element ]**

If you want determine which element raised the key event, you could examine the event.target.tagName property of the event that was raised.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {

    // if the key occurred in an input element...just exit 

    if(event.target.tagName=="INPUT"){ return; }

    // the keystroke wasn't in an input element, do your stuff!

    ...
```

Comment: That's an option.  I'd prefer a way to have canvas be the default for input, unless the cursor is on a text box.

Comment: If you want to exclude key events from text boxes, you could examine the event.target.tagName property of the event that was raised and not process tagName=="INPUT".  See my edited answer.